# Error Loading the following Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone please tell me what's wrong with the following code.  I'm guessing it has something to do with missing brackets for the Javascript, but I can't put my finger on it.  We're using Full Calendar + Mandrill
Thanks a lot!

```
$(window).load(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev,next today'
        },
        defaultDate: '2016-03-15',
        events: [

            {
                title: 'Event',
                start: '2016-03-26T11:00:00',
                end: '2016-03-26T12:00:00',
            },
        ],
        eventClick: function(event) {
            console.log(event)
                // alert(event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'))
                start = event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
                end = event.end.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
                html = '<p>Starts: ' + start + '<p>';
            html += '<p>Ends: ' + end + '<p>';
            var modal = $("#modal");
            modal.find(".modal-title").html(event.title);
            modal.find('.modal-body').html(html)
            modal.modal();



jQuery(function($) {
 $("#contact_form").submit(function() {
    var email = $("#email").val(); // get email field value
    var name = $("#name").val(); // get name field value
    var msg = $("#msg").val(); // get message field value
    var content = "Hello "+name+ ", You have signed "+modal+ " up to XYZ";
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
            data: {
                'key': 'api',
                'message': {
                    'from_email': "email",
                    'text': "Hello ",
                    'from_name': "name",
                    'headers': {
                        'Reply-To': "email"
                    },
                    'subject': 'Confirmation - Sign Up',
                    'text': content,
                    'to': [{
                        'email': email,
                        'name': name,
                        'type': 'to'
                    }]

                }
            }
      }
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            alert('You have been signed up. Thank you!'); // show success message
            $("#name").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
            $("#email").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
            $("#msg").val(''); // reset field after successful submission

        })
        .fail(function(response) {
            alert('Error sending message.');
        });
    return false; // prevent page refresh
});
});
});
});
}); //]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First your code should have proper indentation,
2. You have some errors in the closing of braces and like  so for eg: you have an extra closing brace in ajax call and few others, which I have corrected and pasted.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'prev,next today'
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-03-15',
            events: [

                {
                    title: 'Event',
                    start: '2016-03-26T11:00:00',
                    end: '2016-03-26T12:00:00',
                },
            ],
            eventClick: function(event) {
                console.log(event)
                    // alert(event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'))
                    start = event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
                    end = event.end.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
                    html = '<p>Starts: ' + start + '<p>';
                html += '<p>Ends: ' + end + '<p>';
                var modal = $("#modal");
                modal.find(".modal-title").html(event.title);
                modal.find('.modal-body').html(html)
                modal.modal();
            }  
        )}


        jQuery(function($) {
         $("#contact_form").submit(function() {
            var email = $("#email").val(); // get email field value
            var name = $("#name").val(); // get name field value
            var msg = $("#msg").val(); // get message field value
            var content = "Hello "+name+ ", You have signed "+modal+ " up to XYZ";
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
                    data: {
                        'key': 'api',
                        'message': {
                            'from_email': "email",
                            'text': "Hello ",
                            'from_name': "name",
                            'headers': {
                                'Reply-To': "email"
                            },
                            'subject': 'Confirmation - Sign Up',
                            'text': content,
                            'to': [{
                                'email': email,
                                'name': name,
                                'type': 'to'
                            }]

                        }
                    }
              
                })
                .done(function(response) {
                    alert('You have been signed up. Thank you!'); // show success message
                    $("#name").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
                    $("#email").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
                    $("#msg").val(''); // reset field after successful submission

                })
                .fail(function(response) {
                    alert('Error sending message.');
                });
            return false; // prevent page refresh
        });
    });
});
```

Please check now.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering!  I tried your edits, but it didn't work.  Here is the link to the page with the code if you want to check it out w/ Inspect Element.  Thanks again! http://volunteerships-161619.nitrousapp.com:5000/truett-elementary-school.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what you expect ?

```
$(window).load(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev,next today'
        },
        defaultDate: '2016-03-15',
        events: [

            {
                title: 'Event',
                start: '2016-03-26T11:00:00',
                end: '2016-03-26T12:00:00',
            },
        ],
        eventClick: function (event) {
            console.log(event)
            // alert(event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'))
            start = event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
            end = event.end.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
            html = '<p>Starts: ' + start + '<p>';
            html += '<p>Ends: ' + end + '<p>';
            var modal = $("#modal");
            modal.find(".modal-title").html(event.title);
            modal.find('.modal-body').html(html)
            modal.modal();
          }
       });
    });
});
jQuery(function ($) {
$("#contact_form").submit(function () {
    var email = $("#email").val(); // get email field value
    var name = $("#name").val(); // get name field value
    var msg = $("#msg").val(); // get message field value
    var content = "Hello " + name + ", You have signed " + modal + " up to XYZ";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
        data: {
            'key': 'api',
            'message': {
                'from_email': "email",
                'text': "Hello ",
                'from_name': "name",
                'headers': {
                    'Reply-To': "email"
                },
                'subject': 'Confirmation - Sign Up',
                'text': content,
                'to': [{
                    'email': email,
                    'name': name,
                    'type': 'to'
                }]

            }
        }
    })
})
.done(function (response) {
    alert('You have been signed up. Thank you!'); // show success message
    $("#name").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
    $("#email").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
    $("#msg").val(''); // reset field after successful submission

})
.fail(function (response) {
    alert('Error sending message.');
});
return false; // prevent page refresh
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!  I tried it, but it didn't work.  Here is the link to the page the code is on if you want to check it out through Inspect Element.  http://volunteerships-161619.nitrousapp.com:5000/truett-elementary-school.html  Thanks again!